# static value shared between context, in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, static, singleton

I noticed a really strange behavior in my current project :
I have two contexts
Both use the same library, within there is singleton, a servicelocator

Both load the servicelocator at the beginning.
Strange is, that when the second context is loaded, it takes the singleton instance of the first one-> the instance is not empty, before I initialize it.
How can it be so, and more important : How can I avoid this?

Comment: show some code for us to evaluate.

Comment: Where do you put the library jar file?